# is map function is not working or fetched data have some problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

getting error (Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')) while rendering list. the code is attached below
please help.
REACT Code in which Data have been fetched and tried rendered.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
// import axios from 'axios';
export default class List extends Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state={apiResponse:[]};
    
  }
callAPI()
  {
    fetch("http://localhost:9000/testAPI")  
    .then( (res) => res.json()) 
    .then( (data) => {this.setState({apiResponse: data.task});});
  }

  componentWillMount()
  {
    this.callAPI();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          
        <h1>{this.state.apiResponse}</h1>
        {
            this.state.apiResponse.map((r)=>
                <li >r.task</li>
            )
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

NODE JS from where the data is being fetched to react

```
router.get("/",function(req,res)
{

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("to-do");
    // var query = { address: "Park Lane 38" };
        dbo.collection("to-do").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            res.json(result)
            // res.send((result))
            db.close();
        });
    });

   
})
```

Comment: try to log your state In the render method and check what is in your state before return `JSX`

Comment: What is the output of console.log in your nodeJS-Function? Does it have a property named "task"?

Comment: An empty array is being shown but when turned res.json to res.text() then the text is rendered easily with empty array again in console.

Comment: Yes it has the property named as task

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your json response is not including the task-property (at least not every time). By setting apiResponse to this value you are setting it to undefined and the map-function is not available anymore. A workaround could be to check if the property task is available before setting the state.

```
fetch("http://localhost:9000/testAPI")  
    .then( (res) => res.json()) 
    .then( (data) => {
       if (data.task) {
          this.setState({apiResponse: data.task});
       }
    });
```

Comment: but if we skip the task property and fetching whole data then still showing the same error
while setting res.text() is perfectly rendering

Comment: The data-property is not an array but an object, which doesn't have a map-method as far as I know. Or is it also undefined then?